# j2se application best practice

Tags: java, jdbc

i want to build a simple CRUD console application which consists of a set of 10-20 classes that need access to CRUD methods.
I do not want to create a connection each time in every method that needs db access. Maybe put all the creation part into a separate singleton class ?
Any ideas, best practices how this kind of application should be structured ?

Comment: Just what you need check this one http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html

Comment: thanks, great tutorial, add this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one tutorial is sufficient to learn [How to design DAO](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

Answer (score 1):

A quick but overeengineered solution for simple CRUD would be to use Netbeans JPA wizards:

- Entity Classes from Database (Check the *Adding Entities* part of [this](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html#addEntity))
- JPA Controller classes from Entities ([Small sample](http://www.ensode.net/roller/dheffelfinger/entry/automated_dao_generation_from_jpa))

No handling connections needed.

Comment: this is also an elegant solution, but i want to keep things as simple/fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class with all the functionalities as a seperate method. For example as follows.

Connection getConnection() - returns connection object

void close() - closes the connection

Like this implement  method for each functionality. Extend your operations class to this base class and call required functions.

Ex:

```
 public class Insert extends Base {

// call the rquired functions

}
```

If needed you can parametetrise some variables like drivernames, url, username , password etc.,

Comment: So we will have one class per operation Insert, Update, Delete, Select are you sure you want do this ?